# .setAttribute doesn't work in for-loop - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

i have a small problem with my JS-Script. I tried to give each element in an array a different number, those numbers were also set in an array. Of course i used a for-loop. Now outside the for-loop, this just works fine.

```
var i = 0;
document.getElementsByClassName("MosaikBilder")[i].setAttribute("value", BilderListe[i]);
```

but as soon as i put this into a for-loop, the whole script is not executable. The Browser simply wont load the script.

```
var AlleBilder = document.getElementsByClassName("MosaikBilder");
for(i=0; i<AlleBilder.length -1; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("MosaikBilder")[i].setAttribute("value", BilderListe[i]);
}
```

And to understand this a little bit better, the html and css:

HTML:

```
<div class="padding"></div>
<img class="MosaikBilder" src="B1.png" value=0 >
<img class="MosaikBilder" src="B2.png" value=0 >
<img class="MosaikBilder" src="B3.png" value=0 >
<img class="MosaikBilder" src="B4.png" value=0 >
<img class="MosaikBilder" src="B5.png" value=0 >
<img class="MosaikBilder" src="B6.png" value=0 >
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div class="padding"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
    title {
        display: none;
    }

    .padding {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: red;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .MosaikBilder {
        margin: 10px;
        float: left;
    }
```

BilderListe is an normal array, it gets produced by the following JS:

```
function Zahlenzuweisung(){
    for(var i=0 ; i<BilderListe.length; i++){
        BilderListe[i] = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
        if(BilderListe[i] > 1000){
            BilderListe[i] = 1000;
        }
    }
```

The Array contains 15 random generated numbers and seems to be fine. Everything else with the array works just fine.

Any suggestions why the whole script doesnt get executed as soon as i put the one line of code into the for-loop?

Any help is greatly appreciated, i am relatively new and thankful for every kind of help :)

EDIT: Here is the Fiddle. Its my first one, so it might be fail at some edges
https://jsfiddle.net/ugdb1423/6/

Note: The whole idea behind the script is to rearrange the pictures each time you load the page. I started with generating a list of random numbers without any doubled ones. Once this is done i want to get all Pictures in a list and give them one of the random numbers. Then i want to sort this list, remove the pictures and put them back in the new order. To store the generated number i thought of using the "value" Attribute. And like i said, it seems to work outside the for-loop but not inside.

Comment: Can you make a js fiddle

Comment: Well, one thing, don't repeat your selector in your loop.  Use the variable you are looping over.

Comment: I think there is a bigger issue here we are missing.  `img` elements do not have a value attribute ....  Your logic doesn't make sense.

Comment: actually you should be accessing array[i] so in your code it would be AlleBilder[i] in forloop

Comment: Thanks a lot so far. I added a Fiddle as good as i could (was my first one) and a little note to understand the whole script.

Comment: In the Fiddle i have the AlleBilder[i] Version as a comment, tried this even before the document. version but it didnt work as well

Answer (score 0):

I could not really understand how do you generate the 'BilderListe' array, but containing 15 randomly generated numbers each of which is maximum 1000, you can create an array inside the 'Zahlenzuweisung' as the code follows:

```
var BilderListe = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  var num = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
  if(num > 1000){
    num = 1000;
    BilderListe.push(num);
  }else {
    BilderListe.push(num);
  }
}
```

then you can use this following script to alter each value of the images

```
var AlleBilder = document.getElementsByClassName("MosaikBilder");
for(i=0; i<AlleBilder.length -1; i++){
  AlleBilder[i].setAttribute("value", BilderListe[i]);
}
```

But beware that you can use it if this code snippet is inside the 'Zahlenzuweisung' function. Because the 'BilderListe' array is declared locally to the function. If you want to use it globally, take the

```
var BilderListe = [];
```

declaration outside the function

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! I edited my post wit ha fiddle where you can see the whole script. BilderListe is global and the for-loop just like the one you posted. But it still wont load at all. As soon as i change the for-loop and remove the .setAttribute code, it opens up again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found:

It actually was the last function you can see in the fiddle.
I dont know why, but since the function works with AlleBilder 
it propably made some complications.

Thanks to everyone who helped! :)